# Setting a unique set of keys into a new array

Tags: reactjs, sorting, key

I have a array of objects:

let data = [{
"Borough": "Bronx",
"Neghborhood": "Baychester"
},
{
"Borough": "Bronx",
"Neghborhood": "Bedford Park"
},
{
"Borough": "Queens",
"Neghborhood": "Astoria"
},
{
"Borough": "Queens",
"Neghborhood": "Auburndale"
},   {
"Borough": "Manhattan",
"Neghborhood": "Midtown East"
},
{
"Borough": "Manhattan",
"Neghborhood": "Midtown South"
},
{
"Borough": "Manhattan",
"Neghborhood": "Midtown West"
}, {
"Borough": "Brooklyn",
"Neghborhood": "Prospect Park"
},
{
"Borough": "Brooklyn",
"Neghborhood": "Prospect Park South"
},
{
"Borough": "Brooklyn",
"Neghborhood": "Red Hook"
}];

I want to iterate over it and create a new array that wil hold the unique keys ,
let newArr = ["Bronx, "Brooklyn", "Manhattan", "Queens"].

What i tried is:

```html
    const getUniqueValues = data.map((elm, i) => {
       
        let newArr  = [];
        if (!newArr.includes(elm['Borough'])) {
            newArr.push(elm.Borough)
        }
       
        return newArr;
       
     }
    )
```

but it gives me back just an array of elements with each element inside an array of its own,
so i understand that that's what map does, however i don't understand why the duplicates remain.
Also, i'm  sure that i'm over computing it so i would love suggestions on the most simple code.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `reduce` function:

```js
let data = [{ "Borough": "Bronx", "Neghborhood": "Baychester" }, { "Borough": "Bronx", "Neghborhood": "Bedford Park" }, { "Borough": "Queens", "Neghborhood": "Astoria" }, { "Borough": "Queens", "Neghborhood": "Auburndale" }, { "Borough": "Manhattan", "Neghborhood": "Midtown East" }, { "Borough": "Manhattan", "Neghborhood": "Midtown South" }, { "Borough": "Manhattan", "Neghborhood": "Midtown West" }, { "Borough": "Brooklyn", "Neghborhood": "Prospect Park" }, { "Borough": "Brooklyn", "Neghborhood": "Prospect Park South" }, { "Borough": "Brooklyn", "Neghborhood": "Red Hook" }];

const reduced = data.reduce((carry, current) => {
  if(!carry.some(e => e.Borough == current.Borough)){
    carry.push(current);
  }
  return carry;
}, []);

console.log(reduced)
```